# Read and use private key to sign data in node js [OpenSSL & PHP Example]

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, encryption, pyopenssl

I've been trying for a while to rewrite a php code into node.js, but I've encountered a problem.

This is the PHP code I'm stuck on (a little bit modified):

```
$fp = fopen($privateKeyFileName, "r");
$priv_key = fread($fp, 8192);   
fclose($fp);

echo "PRIVATE KEY: <br/><br/>";
var_dump($priv_key);


$pkeyid = openssl_pkey_get_private($priv_key, $privateKeyPassword);

echo " <br/><br/>PRIVATE KEY ID: <br/><br/>";
var_dump($pkeyid);

openssl_sign($message, $signature, $pkeyid);
openssl_free_key($pkeyid);

echo " <br/><br/>SIGNATURE: <br/><br/>";
var_dump($signature);

$message .= $signature;

echo " <br/><br/>END MESSAGE: <br/><br/>";
var_dump($message);
```

The part I'm stuck on is: `openssl_pkey_get_private`. I'm not sure how to replicate it. I tried skipping it, a let `crypto` (nodejs) do the work, but with no luck.

The interesting thing that needs to be done is: everytime, when I sign the message, `$signature` has 128 characters (string). This is an requirement, and this is my problem in node.

This is my nodejs code:

```
function signData(data) {
    var sign = crypto.createSign('RSA-SHA256');
    sign.update(data);
    var signed = sign.sign(privateKey);
    return signed;
}
```

And another thing, this `RSA-SHA256` has to be SHA1withRSA. This example never generates exactly 128 char string. It returns a buffer, and no matter how I parse or convert it, I can't achieve the requirement. I'm using the same private key on both examples.

Any ideas?